# Grails RESTFUL web service api

Tags: web-services, api, rest, grails

I am currently developing a web app which should do restful service calls to existing web service api.

What I have is the base URL and the API names.

Any help on how do I start working on it?
I suppose I need to use httpbuilder for the base url I have, then followed by /api name. But how do I test it on grails if its working?

When I paste the base url on the browser it does return some xml information, so what I need is to do it on grails instead.

XML response when I paste the url through browser

```
<ns1:createNewUserResponse>
<userId>21</userId>
</ns1:createNewUserResponse>
```

So I need to be able to get this response through my web-app (grails) instead of pasting it on the browser.

EDIT*
this is a good example I found useful

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.0-RC2' )
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*

def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com' )

// perform a GET request, expecting JSON response data
http.request( GET, JSON ) {
  uri.path = '/ajax/services/search/web'
  uri.query = [ v:'1.0', q: 'Calvin and Hobbes' ]

  headers.'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 Ubuntu/8.10 Firefox/3.0.4'

  // response handler for a success response code:
  response.success = { resp, json ->
    println resp.statusLine

    // parse the JSON response object:
    json.responseData.results.each {
      println "  ${it.titleNoFormatting} : ${it.visibleUrl}"
    }
  }

  // handler for any failure status code:
  response.failure = { resp ->
    println "Unexpected error: ${resp.statusLine.statusCode} : ${resp.statusLine.reasonPhrase}"
  }
}
```

but i do not understand the query part and how do I alter it to my need?
the URL I have contains credential of username and password, the response should return a securityToken which I need to get it out from the results. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This XML looks more like SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [groovy-wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite), it provides both SOAP and REST webservice clients.

Answer (score 0):

To make a call to a resfull service look at Groovy HttpBuidler - http://groovy.codehaus.org/HTTP+Builder

Comment: Thank you i found this to be helpful, but do you mind explaining? because I have no idea how to alter it to my need. especially the uri.query part which i think is the key?

Comment: Which part do you need help with? the uri.query is defining the query params that will be passed. For example in the above example you would have the request : /ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q="Calvin and Hobbes" url encoded of course. That would be the request sent to the endpoint. The  response.success block defines what happens when there is a success (200 range response from the endpoint ) and response.failure defines what to do when the server responds with a failure.